# CMake for openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I have the following problem, although my project is building properly using CMake, after that I have error, that 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' cannot be found. I am posting my CMakelists.txt configuration and I would be very grateful for your help. I would also add that 'find package(OPENCV REQUIRED)' is not working.

```
if(MSVC)
if(NOT OPENCV_ROOT)
set(OPENCV_ROOT "D:/OpenCV")
endif()
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR "${OPENCV_ROOT}/build/include")
set(OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIR"${OPENCV_ROOT}/build/x64/vc14/lib")
endif()
```

Comment: "`find package(OPENCV REQUIRED)` is not working": that is your real problem, you shouldn't use OpenCV like you did. What do you mean by "not working"? What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

```
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR})
```